# Rails 4 Undefined Local Variable or Method for Download link

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I keep getting undefined local variable or method `orders_download_template_path' for #<#:0x0000376c505098>

with the following code.  I have also tried download_template_path and @orders_download_template_path (this last one doesn't throw an error, but does nothing either).

Routes.rb:

```
  resources :orders do   
    collection do
      post :import
      get  :upload_page, as: 'upload_page'
      get  :search, as: 'search'
      get  :csv_report, as: 'csv_report'
      get  :overdue_csv_report, as: 'overdue_csv_report'
      get  :download_template, as: 'download_template'
    end
  end
```

orders_controller.rb:

```
  def download_template
    send_file Rails.root.join('public/upload_template.csv'),
    type: 'application/csv',
    x_senfile: true
  end
```

view:

```
<%= link_to "Blank Upload Template", orders_download_template_path %>
```

The File has been Placed under /public

Comment: Could you run rake routes in your console and print the result please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the Rails routing guide, you have a syntax error.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-collection-routes

This should fix it

```
download_template_orders_path
```

Comment: I keep doing that; putting the controller name in the wrong spot.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `rake routes` on your console, you should see the following line (among others):

```
 download_template_orders GET    /orders/download_template(.:format)   orders#do
```

as you can see, if you're setting this route on a COLLECTION, the path generate would be download_template_orders_path.

If you set it on a MEMBER, you would see this:

```
 download_template_order GET    /orders/:id/download_template(.:format)  orders#
```

Answering your question, the correct path would be `download_template_orders_path`